# Using JAXB to annotate an object from an external library

Tags: java, xml, marshalling, jaxb2

Exists a way by using **JAXB** v.2.2.7 to specify the marshalling/unmarshalling of an object from a class defined in an external library? I guess that an adapted must be defined, but how can I notice that the object has my adapter?

E.g.
I use `Interval`, from *Joda* library. If I annotate the `Interval` object into a class as follows:

```
@XmlElement(name="DateInterval")
protected Interval dateInterval;
```

Then an empty tag is created during the marshalling process, i.e.

```
<DateInterval/>
```

Of course, this was expected since none annotated the `Interval` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Joda library you can create a JAXB `XmlAdapter` for types such as `Interval`.  Then you can reference that `XmlAdapter` at the package level so that all mapped fields/properties of that type that belong to classes in that package will apply the `XmlAdapter`.

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=DateTime.class,
        value=DateTimeAdapter.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=DateMidnight.class,
        value=DateMidnightAdapter.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=LocalDate.class,
        value=LocalDateAdapter.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=LocalTime.class,
        value=LocalTimeAdapter.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=LocalDateTime.class,
        value=LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
})
package blog.jodatime;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters;

import org.joda.time.DateMidnight;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html

Comment: Errr! I know how to define adapters, but how can I reference the adapter at the package level?

Comment: Thank you and congrats for the complete post: what a great coincidence making a Joda-based example :)